# Select ALL objects of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering that I didn't find a way to select just all of my array objects. Isn't it possible?

My objects array example:

```js
var objects = {
  House: `some stuff`,
  Car: `some stuff`,
  Dog: `some stuff`,
  Boat: `some stuff`
};

var all = ["House", "Car", "Dog", "Boat"];
var find = all.map(name => objects[name]);
var allOutput = Group(find);
```

For "`all`" I tried:

```
var all = [];
var all = [""];
var all = ["*"];
```

Aso., but nothing worked.

**Expected output:**
I want to get all the data by every key [name], including the key.

Comment: What's the expected output? Are you trying to recreate: `Object.keys(objects)` or `Object.values(objects)`?

Comment: I want to get all objects data, of every key name.

Comment: What is `Group()`?

Comment: Object.keys(obj)

Comment: @Pepe can you answer whether `Object.values()` or `Object.keys()` works for you?

Comment: @Barmar Just an external function, the above example works ;) ... but at the moment I have to select every object by key. I just want to get all in one line, if possible?

Comment: @Pepe or you can use Object.entries() for getting both keys and values

Comment: @Ping & adiga Thx for the tipps. Will try it!